# (KnockoutJS) Referring data outside the foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to bind a data from outside the `foreach` data for each row using `$parent` but it throws an error `Unable to parse bindings` for a code below:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col_name">Name</th>
            <th class="col_dob">DOB</th>
            <th class="col_address">Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { id: resource.id}, style: { background-color: $parent.isSel}, event:{click: $parent.selectRow} ">
            <td class="col_name" data-bind="text: resource.name"></td>
            <td class="col_dob" data-bind="text: resource.birthDate"></td>
            <td class="col_address" data-bind="text: resource.address"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I will remove `style: { background-color: $parent.isSel}, event:{click: $parent.selectRow}` all works fine.

KnockoutJS part for both above looks so far like:

```
this.isSel = ko.observable("#fff");

this.selectRow = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isSel("#ccc");
    console.log("Row selected");
}
```

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `$parent` usage but with the property name: `background-color`.

Dashes **are not valid** in JS object property names. So you need to wrap `background-color` in quotes:

```
<tr data-bind="attr: { id: resource.id}, 
               style: { 'background-color': $parent.isSel}, 
               event:{click: $parent.selectRow} ">
```

See also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html#note-applying-css-classes-whose-names-arent-legal-javascript-variable-names).

Comment: Almost there - no clue why I'm getting `TypeError: self.isSel is not a function` error on a click event. Should I aim `$parent` in that functions as well?

Comment: When you are using the `$parent` the `this` not points to your actual parent, so you need to `bind` it: `event:{click: $parent.selectRow.bind($parent)}` or move the `var self = this;` outside of your `selectRow` to your main viewModel function object